# What is the difference between investing in index fund on their website over your existing bank?

Tags: united-states, index-fund, vanguard

I want to start investing in index fund S&P500, specifically VFIAX from Vanguard. I went to their website and started creating an account, and then it occurred to me....maybe my bank, Chase already has that feature....indeed it does. With my existing Chase You Invest account, I could easily find the VFIAX and set up periodic payments. Now question.... What is the catch? I called to Chase, and a representative redirected my 10 times, and after hours of waiting and talking to representative, I realized they don't know anything.

Question: should I create an account with Vanguard? Or go the easy way: use my existing account with Chase and invest this way. Maybe there are some hidden fees or something I'm not aware of???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will probably be transaction fees if you buy them through Chase. I can't see what that is, but [in fidelity, for example, there's a $75 transaction fee](https://fundresearch.fidelity.com/mutual-funds/summary/922908710).

If you buy them in a Vanguard account, those fees can be waived (as long as you sign up for paperless statements). You can also avoid the fees in Chase by buying [VOO](https://investor.vanguard.com/etf/profile/voo) (unless they still charge commission), which is the same thing but in the form of an ETF. You can see this on Vanguard's site:

https://investor.vanguard.com/mutual-funds/profile/fees/vfiax

...where it says "Also available as an ETF", which links to VOO.

Comment: THere you go the fee. Now it is clear

Comment: I read here https://www.chase.com/personal/investments/you-invest/pricing it says 0 fees .

Comment: okay, cool. i know a lot of brokers have gone commission-free in the last year or so, but didn't know if chase was one of them